Error while trying to connect to my wifi
I'm getting this log Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 192.168.0.1. while trying to connect to my home wifi, it used to connect then stopped. it still connects on Lan cable (I have a DNS configured on this but not wifi) but refuses with wifi. I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04
`
